# How to install my custom R package in a Jupyter r-environment

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm using an r-environment in a Jupyter notebook, but i'm struggling to install or load my custom package.

When I use Rstudio, the package works fine and I use the command bellow to install it:

`install.packages("D:/Modelagem/panR_1.0.tar.gz",repos=NULL, type="source")`

Has anyone already used a custom R package in Jupyter r-enviroment?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to upload the `tar.gz` file to the Jupyter environment.

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

The file will then show up locally as shown in the screenshot and if you create a notebook in the same folder, the uploaded file will be local to it. This code would then install it.

```
install.packages("package.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: I do exactly like this. But I am getting an error "installation of package '' had non-zero exit status". Does anyone know how to fix it? I am trying to install TSA package.